# On Careers, does working remotely mean in an another country?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Generally speaking, when a company says it allows working remotely, does that mean it allows working from another country or perhaps only from another state in the USA or whatever?

Comment: Everything is possible.  Working remotely is something straightforward within US and within EU. On the other hand, working from another country might have implications on the tax side, you cannot know, if not by asking, what a particular employer wants.

Comment: @Antonio ok got u

Comment: Sometimes there are legal issues when being a digital nomad, some questions are already asked in [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/) and in [Expats.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't say for certain *in general*, but on Careers, it's safe to assume that yes, they mean anywhere in the world. We generally enforce this rule unless the client has a very specific reason like requiring government security clearance and that must be clearly stated in the listing.